# Which type of ANOVA?

Tags: anova, multivariate-analysis

I would like some help in which type of analysis (ANOVA) would be the best for the following information:
Tests dealt with whether a good or bad day tomorrow versus a good or bad day one year into the future is viewed as being better or worse. Subjects had to rate possible future events from -3 (most negative) to 3 (most positive), with zero being neutral.
So the variables are good day, bad day, tomorrow, one year and how they are viewed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dependent variable is ordinal, you probably want ordinal logistic regression. But your independent variables are very unclear; it sounds like they should be "type of day" and "date of prediction".  What you've got written here looks like the levels of your independent variables.